# Can't send REQ tokens with Metamask Chrome Extension

Tags: myetherwallet, metamask

I sent some REQ tokens to my Metalink chrome extension. I had to add the REQ token myself, and I received the tokens I sent successfully. However, when I try to send some of my tokens anywhere, Metamask automatically restricts me from sending anything but ETHER.

[image]

I went to MyEtherWallet, connected to Metamask and successfully selected 283 REQ tokens to be send to an address. However, after I confirm my transfer detail on MEW and it opens my Metamask chrome extension, I get this screen:

[image]

I can't find anyone else who had a similar problem. I thought that Metamask might have disabled token transaction for some time, but that doesn't really makes sense to me. especially as I sent the tokens through MyEtherWallet.

Is there anyone who might know what is the problem and why my REQ tokens are trapped in Metamask?

edit: I did add the REQ token and a valid contract address from https://etherscan.io/token/0x8f8221afbb33998d8584a2b05749ba73c37a938a?a=0x2fa35a2773f720ddc374e8efb4a82fc4594425d8

Here is a screenshot of my Metamask interface
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your ether balance is 0, which is insufficient to pay the fee for the transaction you're doing. All transactions in Ethereum require gas, and ether is used to pay for that gas. Transfer some ether into that account and try again. (You should need less than a dollar's worth of ether.)

Comment: thanks, I already figured it out but that really was the problem

Comment: I wasn't aware that I had to pay the fee with Ether, and the Metamask interface made me think the transaction is being made with Ethreum

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that Metamask doesn't support REQ natively. You may have to add the token to Metamask manually by clicking into the "Tokens" tab and clicking "Add Token", then inputting the REQ token address (0x8f8221afbb33998d8584a2b05749ba73c37a938a)

Comment: that is exactly what I did.. note that already have REQ tokens on my Metamask extension and they do show when I enter it. only when I try to send them via MyEtherWallet for an example, it only let's me pay with ETH

Comment: The ETH that it's asking for is to cover the gas of the transaction. I believe the transaction will successfully transfer the tokens--when you "send" tokens, you're actually making a call to the token contract to move that balance from your address to another. As such, you need ETH to pay the gas needed for that transaction.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pay the gas as the guy stated - or no ones going to confirm the transaction. Everyone has to pay the ferryman dude...! Load up with a few dollars of ethereum and do it again - you will need to submit the transaction fee through your MetaMask wallet as you showed

Comment: That answer has already been given.